# Can't move Azure CDN Endpoint from one resource group to another

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cdn

I'm trying to move CDN endpoint resources from one subscription to another subscription but I'm getting the following error. I have the CDN profile and endpoint in same RG.

> Identifier
> '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/internal/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/internal-cdn/endpoints/internal-cdn-endpoint'
> is not a top level resource.

Can you please provide some suggestions to move the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error say the CDNEndpoint it's below a CDN Profile, you can't move an CND EndPoint directly, you have to move the entire CDN Profile to the Target Resource Group.

I make a quickly test and I was able to move the CDN profile with any problem, both with the move button of the portal and with the following powershell commands:

```
$SourceAID = (Get-AzureRmResource –ResourceGroupName "ResouceGroupFROM" -ResourceName "CDNPROFILE-NAME").ResourceID  
Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName "ResouceGroupTARGET" -ResourceId $SourceAID
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nacho. yes, I have selected both CDN profile and endpoint during move operation and it still fails with that error.

Comment: Your're welcome,  How are you doing the move, with a powershell command? can you edit your question and add that information??

Comment: interesting thing, I tried using the PowerShell command and I was able to the profile along with endpoint. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect man! Vote and mark the answer as valid! Thanks!